# Как получить список трансляций с YouTube-канала?

Tags: youtube-api

Возникла необходимость вывести все трансляции с [автоматически созданного канала](https://www.youtube.com/channel/UCNh14TBrhjDxYppWS-lwRRw/live).
Возможно ли это сделать средствами YouTube API? Как должен выглядеть запрос?

Я пробовал функции:

- search.list
- liveBroadcasts.list
- liveStreams.list

Но ни с одной не удалось это сделать.

Answer (score 0):

Как раз средствами `search.list` все и делается. Возможно вы не так составляли запрос?

Возможно ошибка была в ID. ID канала, который вы скинули:

> UC-9BUEcqS3pqlci0yrPJJLg

(можете перейти на главную страницу канала и скопировать из адресной строки).

Запрос должен быть примерно такой:

> https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/search/?type=video&maxResults=25&eventType=live&part=snippet&key={YOUR_API_KEY}&channelId=UC-9BUEcqS3pqlci0yrPJJLg

Вот, собственно, ответ:

```html
{
 "kind": "youtube#searchListResponse",
 "etag": "\"XpPGQXPnxQJhLgs6enD_n8JR4Qk/f0dA1GdWenwL7H1e4fAyCFLqtq4\"",
 "regionCode": "RU",
 "pageInfo": {
  "totalResults": 1,
  "resultsPerPage": 25
 },
 "items": [
  {
   "kind": "youtube#searchResult",
   "etag": "\"XpPGQXPnxQJhLgs6enD_n8JR4Qk/KlsGNkIFZpLFx2wZGo8htbQkxx0\"",
   "id": {
    "kind": "youtube#video",
    "videoId": "973Cqusq3XI"
   },
   "snippet": {
    "publishedAt": "2019-02-05T00:18:54.000Z",
    "channelId": "UC-9BUEcqS3pqlci0yrPJJLg",
    "title": "Crossout - Getting Wrecked w/ Expendable & Friends / Live Chat & Support",
    "description": "Support the stream: https://streamlabs.com/insomniactv1.",
    "thumbnails": {
     "default": {
      "url": "https://i.ytimg.com/vi/973Cqusq3XI/default_live.jpg",
      "width": 120,
      "height": 90
     },
     "medium": {
      "url": "https://i.ytimg.com/vi/973Cqusq3XI/mqdefault_live.jpg",
      "width": 320,
      "height": 180
     },
     "high": {
      "url": "https://i.ytimg.com/vi/973Cqusq3XI/hqdefault_live.jpg",
      "width": 480,
      "height": 360
     }
    },
    "channelTitle": "Insomniac TV",
    "liveBroadcastContent": "live"
   }
  }
 ]
}
```

Если вдруг что не получится — пишите.

Comment: Странно. У Вас работает у меня нет. Вот ссыль на эксплорер https://developers.google.com/apis-explorer/#p/youtube/v3/youtube.search.list?part=snippet&channelId=UCNh14TBrhjDxYppWS-lwRRw&eventType=live&maxResults=50&type=video&_h=4&

Comment: Аа, Вы пытаетесь  вывести трансляцию со своего канала. А в моем случае это автоматически созданный топик ютубом.Ваш вариант не работает к сожалению в данном случае.

Comment: я выводил не со своего канала, а с того канала, который вы скинули по его идентификатору

Comment: Расскажите по подробнее, что хотите сделать, мой вариант работает с любым каналом и отображает все трансляции идущие на нем в данный момент.
И еще раз повторюсь, вы используете неверный идентификатор канала:
та трансляция что вы скинули, была на канале с channelId UC-9BUEcqS3pqlci0yrPJJLg
а не UCNh14TBrhjDxYppWS-lwRRw

Comment: Прочтите внимательнее Мне нужно извлечь все трасляции с этого топика https://www.youtube.com/channel/UCNh14TBrhjDxYppWS-lwRRw/live

Comment: По факту там должен быть список каналов с трансляциями из данного топика.

Comment: Потом уже зная идентификаторы можно воспользоваться вашим примером, но сначала нужно получить эти идентификаторы